# Java Swing - user alerts

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to build a user alert mechanism by bringing up the window to the front and then flashing the icon on the screen for the user. I have two questions with regards to this approach:

1. How can you find the current window you are at in Java and then de-minimize it and bring to front?
2. Is there a mechanism in Java that would enable me to simply show the icon for a second or two and then hide it, in the middle of the screen? If not, what would be the way to achieve that?

Thanks a lot for any replies.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> How can you find the current window you are at in Java and then de-minimize it and bring to front

```
Window[] allWindows = Window.getWindows();
```

- returns arrays of all `Top-Level Containers` from current JVM e.g. `J/Frame`, `J/Dialog`(`JOptionPane`), `J/Window`,
- you can to test for (example) `if (allWindows[i] instanceof JFrame) {`
- then [WindowState](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowStateListener.html) returned [WindowEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowEvent.html)

> by bringing up the window to the front and then flashing the icon on the screen for the user

use undecodated `JDialog` (works `toFront`, `toBack`) with

- create only once time
- `setDefaultCloseOperations(HIDE_ON_CLOSE)`
- use `Swing Timer` for hide `JDialog`

> Is there a mechanism in Java that would enable me to simply show the icon for a second or two and then hide it, in the middle of the screen? If not, what would be the way to achieve that?

- have look at `Java Translucent Window`, put there `Icon` to the `JLabel` (or to the `JButton`)

use `Swing Timer` for flashing by hiding `Icon` or swithing bewtween two or more `Icons` (three or four is good)

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest way to get the window ancestor is :
[SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(yourComponent);](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#getWindowAncestor%28java.awt.Component%29)